# What are the key settings to configure when using two routers in a house?

Tags: networking, router

I have a fibre connection, and two routers because of the layout of the building. Basically I go from Fibre > ONT > Ethernet > Router #1 > Ethernet > Router #2.

Both routers are WiFi access points.

My problem is that WiFi device connectivity on Router#2 is erratic and keeps bombing out. So I'm wondering if I understand the configuration requirements correctly.

These are the key points as I understand:

1. Both routers should have static IP Addresses.
2. Only one router should be the DHCP server (IPv4 and IPv6)
3. Should I worry about bridging?
4. WiFi SSID should be different on both routers? Or same?
5. What about the Internet settings? INTERNET_TR069_ADSL_0_100 / INTERNET_TR069_VDSL_VID_10 / INTERNET_TR069_ETH_VID_10 / INTERNET_UMTS? Should they be deleted on router #2 or not?
6. Is there something to do with NATS that I need to do? on Router #2?
7. The two routers are connected Ethernet between their LAN ports.

The WiFi problem in more detail:
I am connected to Router #2, WiFi. Home office. My work issued laptop is connected (Win10). From time to time, maybe under load, maybe every hour or so, it suddenly loses connection. If I Disconnect from the WiFi, and re-connect, it's slow to re-establish the connection, but it works. It's faster than just waiting for a re-connection.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Router #2 as a DHCP relay?

Comment: Please describe your Wi-Fi problems with the second router in greater detail.

Comment: When your device loses internet from router2, does that router still have internet? Do you have router1's LAN port connected to router2's WAN port?

Comment: Router #2 as a DHCP Relay? - have no idea how to make it do that. The concept sounds right though. 
The two routers are connected LAN port to LAN port. Only Router #1 has WAN port to the ONT.

Comment: Just a confirmation for you, right now because of the Lan2Lan connection of the two routers, the second one is only acting as a switch and Access point. no bridging or NAT or firewall work is required because its not acting as a router (which bridging would disable). you have already bypassed most of the gotcha's involving multiple routers in a residence, by the way they are connected, and the fact that you have disabled DHCP on one of them. DHCP relaying should not be required.

Comment: Thanks :) That sweeps a heap of possible causes off the table

Comment: @Cpt.Whale When I lose connectivity on laptop > Router #2, I can still access the  internet from mobile phone > WiFI > Router #2. Which makes me now think it's maybe a laptop issue...

Comment: I thonk tjis is an XY question.  Why do you have 2 routers rather then a router and switch+AP ( Turning the second router into a switch + AP will simplify your network and make WIFI work better.  All it takes is disabling the DHCP server on the router, making sure it has a LAN IP in the same network as the other router but unique and ideally out the dhcp reserved range and to disvonnect the wan port and plug a network cable between one of its LAN ports and a LAN port on the main router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to close this question, because I've discovered that whilst the laptop device has a problem maintaining a connection to the WiFi network, a mobile phone along side does not.

This means the issue lies somewhere else - not in the router.

Thanks for all the advice provided... it has confirmed that a lot of my current configuration is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your network is as follows before troubleshooting the WIFI issues

| Device | WAN Port | LAN Port | DHCP Server | WIFI | IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Router 1 | To ISP Modem | To LAN Port Router 2 | ON | Unique SSID & Unique Channels | 1st IP in subnet |
| Router 2 | - | To LAN Port Router 1 | - | Unique SSID & Unique Channels | IP in Router 1's subnet |

Comment: Yes, that is my current configuration.

Comment: The only thing I'm thinking is maybe my IPv6 DHCP server is still running on both routers...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the router model #s as well as the wifi settings from the two routers.